# after creating the xamarin-android in azure, how do I download the backend as well

Tags: azure, xamarin.android

While learning how to create Android-xamarin-azure application, I must have done steps from different tutorials. I've just created a new test application, and this picture shows what's the final screen.

[image]

This screen is showing that I've already have a connection string and a Todo table. I remember that before I was able to download a backend project. Now, I'm just being told that I've already a table, but I don't know how to download the backend project.

I'd like to download the backend project as well, so that I can start expending it.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow this link. It shows how to download backend project
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#create-app

Comment: It's by following the link you just provided that I got to the screen that I showed in my question. I may have download it before. Now there is no button saying `Download` as before. Maybe it's a one time download,

Comment: Creating a new app can help you

Comment: thanks. That what I did. It seems like it's a one time download. Still learning azur.